# Can verb "feed" have indirect object?

Tags: grammar

I come across line
"And all I wanna do is to feed her lots of treats" In the song "I Love My Kitty Cat". Can verb " Feed" Have indirect object? Is direct object in this line "her" And indirect "lots of treats". If not then what part of speech is " Lots of treats "? Objective compliment?

Comment: @Petro Probka Yes, "lots of treats" is Od and "her" is Oi. You have approved a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the verb can have a direct and indirect object.

In "I feed my cat treats", the indirect object is the cat. The treats are the direct object and the cat is the one who eats them.

The 'treats' could not be an object compliment as you also asked because they aren't adding any detail to an object. An example of an object compliment would be "*treats make my cat happy*", because the cat has become happy.

Comment: "the object of the verb": in the first sentence, the verb has two objects, "my cat" being the direct object and "treats" being the indirect object.  In the second sentence, the verb has only one object, "treats," so it is grammatically the direct object, while "my cat" is the object of the proposition "to" in the adverbial prepositional phrase.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say. In "I feed my cat treats" the direct object is "the treats" and "my cat" is indirect object. In "I feed treats to my cat" the direct object is "treats" and "to my cat" is a preposition phrase functioning as complement of "feed". There is no indirect object.

Comment: @phoog You have got it wrong, too! In the first sentence, "my cat" is indirect object and "treats" is direct object. I agree with what you say about the second sentence, though the prep phrase "to my cat" is not adverbial but a complement of "feed".

Comment: @BillJ yes, I agree.

Comment: @BillJ  It appears that user Astralbee disagrees with you. You have suggested a change in the answer. That is what a comment i for. Ther is no need to argue the matter further. You are free to post  DIFFERENT ANSWER, OF COURSE.

Comment: @DavidSiegel What are you talking about? Who's arguing? I see that Astralbee has corrected his answer, presumably in response to my comment. And in case you hadn't noticed, I did post a different answer, though someone has unbelievably downvoted it.

Comment: @BillJ My apologies. I misread the situation. Your comments were flagged as "no longer needed". I thought it was because Astralbee  had read your comment and did not intend to change the answer. Instead it was because Astralbee  had read the comment and had already changed the answer accordingly. In any case I would not have a problem with a user posting a different answer to one already posted.

Comment: @BillJ Equally as unbelievable as the downvotes on my corrected answer. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

> *And all I wanna do is to feed her lots of treats.*

You are right.

The direct object is "lots of treats" and "her" is indirect object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the verb "feed" can have an indirect object, and it is very common. "I feed X Y" means the same as "I feed Y to X".  (This is true with many verbs in English, e.g. "I gave my sister a cake" = "I gave a cake to my sister.")

I think you explained the rest for yourself.